# Registrar cannot build a signature for array of skeleton interfaces (MTOUCHTASK error MT4111) on device only

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

So here is my problem:

- I have some protocols defined in my objc static library, like this:

  ```
  @protocol IBar;

  @protocol IFoo <NSObject>

  @property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *bars;
  @property(nonatomic, strong) id <IBar> currentBar;

  @end
  ```
- They are bind to Xamarin project like this (I'm using skeleton empty interface IIBar here)

  ```
  // @protocol IBar <NSObject>
  [Protocol, Model]
  [BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
  interface IBar
  {
      // @required @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
      [Export ("name", ArgumentSemantic.Strong)]
      string Name { get; set; }
  }
  interface IIBar {}

  // @protocol IFoo <NSObject>
  [Protocol, Model]
  [BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
  interface IFoo
  {
      // @required @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray * bars;
      [Export ("bars", ArgumentSemantic.Strong)]
      IIBar[] Bars { get; set; }

      // @required @property (nonatomic, strong) id<IBar> currentBar;
      [Export ("currentBar", ArgumentSemantic.Strong)]
      IIBar CurrentBar { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- And implementations of these protocols

  ```
  public class Foo : NSObject, IIFoo 
  {
      //...
  }

  public class Bar : NSObject, IIBar
  {
      //...
  }
  ```

Everything compiles just fine and working on simulator without any problems, but when I try to deploy it on device I get:

> MTOUCHTASK: error MT4111: The registrar cannot build a signature for type `Binding.IIBar[]' in method`XTestApp.Foo.get_Bars`.
>   Task "MTouchTask" execution -- FAILED

Thank you for the reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a problem in Xamarin.iOS, where arrays of protocols aren't working properly.

A workaround would be to to bind as `NSObject[]` or `NSArray`.

I recommend filing a bug about it, so that it can get fixed (http://bugzilla.xamarin.com).